# Name and Algorithms for a Sparsest Circle Packing

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, algorithms, discrete-geometry

The ordinary [circle packing problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circle_packing) in the variant with equal radii asks for the largest radius $r_{max}$ that allows placing $n$ non-overlapping circles with radius $r_{max}$ e.g. in the unit square, in the unit circle or, on the unit sphere ([Tammes' problem](http://en.wikiyy.com/wiki/Tammes_problem)).

Now, I would like to solve a somehow opposite problem:

> **Question:**
>
> given a number $n\in\mathbb{N}$, what is the smallest radius $r_{min}\in\mathbb{R}^+$ that permits a non-overlapping, rigid placement of $n$ circles with radius $r_{min}$ in the unit square, or in the unit circle or, on the unit sphere?

Under a rigid configuration I understand a configuration, where every open halfplane, resp. hemisphere defined by a hyperplane through a circle's center contains at least one contact point with another circle or, with the boundary of the containing region.

Are there already algorithms and/or theoretical results available for that problem?

Comment: To make it clear, you might  illustrate with a penny packing and with a packing where "the central pennies are removed".  In particular, the Pack-o-mania website might talk about rigid packing already.  Gerhard "Some Holes In My Remembering" Paseman, 2018.08.11.

Comment: @GerhardPaseman removing pennies from a packing of course yields a rigid packing, however not necessarily the sparsest possible.

Comment: I am not sure about the added note in the OP that in the square arrangement "certain coins can be moved orthogonally to a side of the square"; notice that the rows of discs in the lower right figure of my answer have a slight curvature, so the discs are kept in place in the same way as for the packing in the circle. I thought that was the whole point of this structure, these five lines of discs along each boundary of the square have a curvature that keeps each disc fixed in place by its neighbors.

Comment: I didn't notice the curvature in the image; I will check what I overlooked.

Comment: After checking the article, I see that it indeed also solves the problem in case of the unit squares. I will remove the addendum.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An overview of this "sparse packing problem" is given by Matthew Kahle in [Sparse locally-jammed disk packings](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/2827/b52f9626d1f09b918208d793a7ea4975439b.pdf). Quite generally, $r_{\rm min}=O(1/n)$, so the fraction of the unit square or unit disc covered by the $n$ circles goes to 0 as their number $n$ goes to infinity. In a disc you just line up the circles along the perimeter, and this works for any smooth boundary. For a polygon, such as a square, the construction is more involved to avoid loose circles at the corners.

[image]

These configurations are called "rigged" or "jammed", meaning that no single circle can move, each is held in place by its neighbors. (It is possible for several circles to move together, they are not "collectively jammed".) Kahle also discusses Monte Carlo algorithms to find such jammed sparse packings.

Comment: that is a good pointer for further search; I'm only missing the solution, if the number $n$ of circles is given.

Comment: if $n$ is given and you can vary $r$, can't you just reduce $r$ until the circles can be lined up along the perimeter of the disc?

Comment: In the case of an enclosing circle that is a solution; but what about the unit square or the surface of the unit sphere?

Comment: On the sphere you can put 2n spheres on the vertices of an antiprism to get O(1/n) again. This is not only "locally" jammed, but really "collectively" jammed. I know of this arrangement from Woden Kusner, and it might be in his 12-sphere-problem paper.

Comment: @YoavKallus --- [12-sphere problem](https://arxiv.org/abs/1611.10297v2) --- it's a very interesting paper, but I did not find the construction you mention (may well have overlooked it, it's also a long paper).